# Javascript: Prevent page refresh via Ctrl and R

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prevent page refresh only when user clicks Ctrl with R.

I try with the preventDefault() method as following but it does not work:

```
function disableCtrlR(s) { if ((s.which || s.keyCode) == 17 && (s.which || s.keyCode) == 82) s.preventDefault(); };
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("keydown", disableCtrlR);
});
```

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks.

PS. I know this is not an ideal solution but this is the only solution for me to solve the bug on my webpage while waiting for the bug to be resolved.

Comment: That condition is guaranteed to be `false`. You should try a debugger to see whether the execution is actually entering the `if` body.

Comment: @JLRishe, I tried to include alert inside the if body, and it displays the alert message when I press Ctrl or R. Any idea?

Comment: Just keep in mind, this is a windows-specific hack. Apple users will use the command key, not the control key.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, thanks for the information.

Comment: Note to everyone: don't do this. It's very annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            var c = e.which || e.keyCode;
            if (c == 82) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
<h1>If you click in here, you won't be able to refresh with Ctrl+R</h1>
<input type="text" />
```

Using jQuery 2.1.1, this will disable reload by Ctrl+R

Comment: @JLRishe why would this *prevent the R key at all*? He does the if ctrlKey check before blocking anything.

Comment: @Kaiido My mistake. I had this answer confused with kemotoe's answer because of Brian's comment.

Comment: @BrianCheong Not sure if capncoolio quickly edited their answer after posting, but this does not prevent entering 'r'.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This is workable for disable pressing Ctrl+R as well. Thanks alot for the help guys.

Answer (score 3):

To check if there is a control key pressed simultaneously in an key event, you'll check for the [`KeyboardEvent.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) property.

```js
// beware ES6 below, will fail in Netscape
onkeydown = e => {
  if(e.key === 'r' && e.ctrlKey){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('ctrl + r')
    }
  }
```

```html
<input autofocus>
```

Addendum:

As you mentioned in your question, this is very-much "*not an ideal solution*". Blocking default browser behavior should be made only on special cases, like here blocking the *ctrl*+*R* shortcut should only be done on some part of a web-application that really needs this shortcut, and not on the document itself. That's part of why I never talked about blocking the page refresh in this answer (which would need some extra work to work in this intent on all platforms).

Comment: Are you assuming OP won't need to use their page on IE? Or are you assuming they're going to use a transpiler?

Comment: @JLRishe this example is only here to show the *KeyboardEvent.ctrlKey* property. How OP will implement it is none of my businesses. ES6 is now supported by a wide range of browsers so I think it's fine to use it in a snippet like that since it is more readable that the important part is  `e.ctrlKey` without extraneous noise.

Comment: What's the point of providing code that OP can't use as-is, given the subject matter? @BrianCheong may not be aware that including your code as it is would cause their entire script to fail if it's loaded in IE. This "not my problem" attitude of yours is pretty crappy if you ask me.

Comment: @JLRishe do you want me to write the whole `if(e.key)... else if(e.which || e.keyCode) ...` and all the other fallbacks needed to support Netscape 3.1? IE is a dead browser, even MS told so, and it's only there for legacy pruposes. All modern browsers (Edge included) do support basics ES6 syntax. That you are not comfortable with it doesn't mean we should stick to old syntaxes forever.(I will add a note for your pleasure).

Comment: @Kaiido 12% of people still use IE. Nobody uses Netscape 3.1. IE is dead in terms of feature adds, but it is still very much alive in terms of usage. If you assume you don't need to support IE, you are assuming that you don't need to support more than one tenth of the people on the internet.

Comment: @JLRishe only numbers that would matter is the percentage of people coming to stackoverflow using IE. I'm all against your idea of code others can use as-is. Blocking ctrl-r on the document is most of the time a bad design. One should apply it only on some target that does need this shortcut, I can't guess what the target will be for others. All I can do is point to the correct property one should read in order to know if there were the ctrl-key pressed. No need to make legacy code for this, this snippet correctly shows how this `ctrlKey` can be used.

Comment: @Kaiido _"Blocking ctrl-r on the document is most of the time a bad design."_ Then you should have mentioned this in your answer. From the code in the question, OP is clearly trying to apply this handler to the whole page. Your code applies the handler to the whole page, so it's entirely plausible that OP would use your code as-is. As I already stated, OP may not realize that doing so would break their entire script on IE and you need to be cognizant of how OP might use your code. If you're not trying to help OP, then what are you doing here?

Comment: @JLRishe from the question "*I know this is not an ideal solution*". Also, OP is using jQuery, there is little chance he will drop it for this code. But I added an addendum for future readers.